# Serbian characters in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have problem with Serbian language in FPDF http://www.fpdf.org/

> $mystring = "Запослени у рачуноводству/сродном радном месту";

I used $pdf->Write and MultiCell... all are same result.

```
utf8_decode($mystring) -> ????????? ? ?????????????/??????? ?????? ?????

iconv('UTF-8', 'utf-8//TRANSLIT', $mystring) -> Ð—Ð°Ð¿Ð3⁄4Ñ•Ð»ÐμÐ1⁄2Ð ̧ Ñƒ Ñ€Ð°Ñ‡ÑƒÐ1⁄2Ð3⁄4Ð2Ð3⁄4Ð ́Ñ•Ñ‚Ð2Ñƒ/Ñ•Ñ€Ð3⁄4Ð ́Ð1⁄2Ð3⁄4Ð1⁄4 Ñ€Ð°Ð ́Ð1⁄2Ð3⁄4Ð1⁄4Ð1⁄4ÐμÑ•Ñ‚Ñƒ
```

thank so much

Comment: What charset is the string in `$mystring`? Only if its's in ISO-8859-1 should you call `utf8_decode()` ([see also this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf_8_decode_encode)). And your call to `iconv()` tries to convert from utf-8 to utf-8 (I dont't think `//TRANSLIT` makes sense for utf-8, as utf-8 should already be able to encode all characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would not use UTF-8 in my PDFs because the file size will big for me. I use font embedding in this case to avoid big file size.

The FPDF class can produce documents in many languages other than the Western European ones: Central European, Cyrillic, Greek, Baltic and Thai, provided you own TrueType or Type1 fonts with the desired character set. UTF-8 support is also available.

For the UTF-8 support you have to use **[tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)** which is based on FPDF. tFPDF accepts UTF-8 encoded text. Please **[read all this instructions](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)** and then download the **[ZIP file](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/dl.php?id=92&f=zip)** on the bottom from this site.

### Convertation to UTF-8:

You do not need a convertation to UTF-8 if you use instructions above (from link) and load a UTF-8 string from a file like follows:

```
// this file file must be saved in UTF-8 before:
$str = file_get_contents('Text-saved-in-UTF-8.txt');
```

**In other case:**

You have to use **[`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)** and not `iconv`.

For Serbian  (Latin) this is either `'iso-8859-2'` or `'windows-1250'`. For Serbian (Cyrillic) this is `'iso-8859-5'` or `'windows-1251'`. These encodings will provide correct display of diacritic Latin characters such as `žćđš`.

In yor case for:

```
$mystring = "Запослени у рачуноводству/сродном радном месту";
```

You have to write:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($mystring, 'UTF-8', 'iso-8859-5');
```

or

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($mystring, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1251');
```

Your PHP file must be saved in `iso-8859-5` or in `windows-1251` before (but **not** in UTF-8).

And then you use this in tFPDF.

Comment: The both iso-8859-5 and windows-1251 are say ��������� � �������������/������� ������ �����

Comment: @camichel, I corrected my answer. Please delete your comments above. I have checked it on my server and it works.