# Bosnian characters in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have an bosnian string $string = "Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul."

I used "Write" function of fpdf http://www.fpdf.org/ but all "č" characters become to "è"

```
$pdf->Write (6, iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1250//TRANSLIT', "Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul."));
```

How can I fix it? thank so much!

Comment: Does it change the characters only when you call the `Write()` method or also when you `echo` the string?

Comment: What you mean echo? this is fpdf.

Comment: If you do this: `iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1250//TRANSLIT', "Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul.")` do you get the right or wrong characters?

Comment: I got wrong character.

Comment: If you echo without the `iconv()` function, do you get the correct characters? Also try the `Write()` function without the `iconv()`.

Comment: You could also try: `iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', "Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul.")` which works for me. With `CP1250//TRANSLIT` I also get some weird characters.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
require_once 'fpdf181\fpdf.php';
require_once 'fpdf181\makefont\makefont.php';

MakeFont('C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf','cp1252');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','Arial.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);
$pdf->Write(6,'Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul.');
$pdf->Output();
```

Try to change the encoding to `cp1250` or `ISO-8859-2`.

Source: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

If all this should fail then try to use UTF-8: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: @MetrobuyVietNam `iconv` converts the string to the right encoding. But then the `Write()` method converts it to another encoding again. You need to use the right encoding in the `Write()` method/function.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use UTF-8 in my PDFs because the file size will big for me. I use font embedding in this case to avoid a big file size.

The FPDF class can produce documents in many languages other than the Western European ones: Central European, Cyrillic, Greek, Baltic and Thai, provided you own TrueType or Type1 fonts with the desired character set. UTF-8 support is also available.

For the UTF-8 support you have to use **[tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)** which is based on FPDF. tFPDF accepts UTF-8 encoded text. Please **[read all this instructions](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)** and then download the **[ZIP file](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/dl.php?id=92&f=zip)** on the bottom from this site.

### Convertation to UTF-8:

You do not need a convertation to UTF-8 if you use instructions above (from link) and load a UTF-8 string from a file like follows:

```
// this file file must be saved in UTF-8 before:
$str = file_get_contents('Text-saved-in-UTF-8.txt');
```

**In other case:**

You have to use **[`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)** and not `iconv`. For Bosnian (Latin) this is `'iso-8859-2'`.

In yor case for:

```
$mystring = "Saglasno odredbama čl.19 Zakona o udruženjima i Statuta Udruženja računovođa i knjigovođa Srbije URIKS iz Beograda, ul.";
```

You have to write:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($mystring, 'UTF-8', 'iso-8859-2');
```

Your PHP file must be saved in `iso-8859-2` before (but **not** in UTF-8).

And then you use this in tFPDF.

---

Related answer from me: [Serbian characters in FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420753/serbian-characters-in-fpdf/51423301#51423301)

Comment: Thank you, I converted cp1250 in font and it working with http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/

Comment: Thank you so much, but I do not use your way.